# Sums of vector spaces and their dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^5$. Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension 3 and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension $4$. What can you say about about the dimensions of $U\cap W$ and $U+W$?

---

Using the fact that ${\rm dim}(U) + {\rm dim}(W) = {\rm dim}(U+W) + {\rm dim}(U\cap W)$, we find ${\rm dim}(U+W) + {\rm dim}(U\cap W) = 3 + 4 = 7.$ Now my question follows here

We know $U\subset U+W \subset V$, thus ${\rm dim}(U)\le{\rm dim}(U+W)\le{\rm dim}(V)$ or $3\le{\rm dim}(U+W)\le5$.

We know $W\subset U+W \subset V$, thus ${\rm dim}(W)\le{\rm dim}(U+W)\le{\rm dim}(V)$ or $4\le{\rm dim}(U+W)\le5$.

Which one is correct and how do I know?

Comment: Hint. Forget about formulas for the moment. You know $W$ is part of $U+W$. What does that say about the dimension of $U+W$?

Comment: Ah of course.. It must therefore have a dimension that is greater than the greatest of $U$ and $W$ separately (in this case $W$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your implications are correct, but the last one gives you more information. That is, if $4 \leq \dim(U + W) \leq 5$ then surely $3 \leq \dim(U + W) \leq 5$.

To see that $\dim(U + W) = 4$ is indeed possible, take $U = \mathrm{Span}\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and $W = \mathrm{Span}\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$.
To see that $\dim(U + W) = 5$ is indeed possible, take $U = \mathrm{Span} \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and $W = \mathrm{Span} \{e_1, e_2, e_4, e_5 \}$.

Here, $(e_1, \ldots, e_5)$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$ so $e_i$ has $1$ in the $i$-th coordinate and $0$ in all other coordinates.